# 'Primary-expression expected' error not using dependent type

Tags: c++, templates, methods

In the following code, the 'bObj->b()' line in main() compiles but the 'cObj->c()' line gives an error 'expected primary-expression before '>' token'.  This doesn't have to do with dependent types; adding 'template' or 'typename' in the appropriate place doesn't help.  Any hint on what the problem is?  In the 'real' version of this code, there are many other template and non-template versions of function 'b'.  The problem may be only occur in one place and not others, but I haven't been able to determine what may be the important difference.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class A {};
class D : public A {};

class B
{
public: 
        template <class T> boost::shared_ptr<T> b() { return boost::shared_ptr<T>(); }
};      

class C
{
public: 
        boost::shared_ptr<A> b() { return boost::shared_ptr<A>(); }
};      

int main(int, char **)
{       
        boost::shared_ptr<C> cObj(new C);
        boost::shared_ptr<B> bObj = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(cObj);

        bObj->b<D>();
        cObj->b<D>();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. If you post a question about a compilation error, please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message, and also please mark out in the code which line it's about.

Answer (score 4):

`C` does not have a member function *template*, only a regular member function. Therefore, you cannot provide template arguments when calling `C::b()`:

```
cObj->b<D>(); // ERROR!
cObj->b(); // OK
```

Moreover:

> In the 'real' version of this code, there are many other template and non-template versions of function 'b'.

Then it's likely that the code you provided is not a good example of the problem you are having in the "real" version of your code.

> The problem may be only occur in one place and not others, but I haven't been able to determine what may be the important difference.

*You* know your code best. We can't make assumptions on what we don't see. If this answer does not solve your issue, I think you should produce a more representative example of what your "real" code does, possibly reducing it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry, the complete error is 'error: expected primary-expression before '>' token' (not much more than I typed originally).  My shortened example does leave out the detail that some of the other definitions of b() in class C are also template methods, so I didn't think that it was C::b hiding template<>B::b.  And, as I said, other places using C::b do not appear to have a problem.